# Rust Undertale Save File Loader

Tags: file-system, rust

This code's job is to load save files from a subfolder in `~/undertale-saves` and save them to `~/.config/UNDERTALE_linux_steamver`. I'd like to know if there's any ways to improve readability, or obvious ways to improve performance or binary size (neither of those are a problem with this code but if it's easy, why not?)

```
use std::{
    fs::{copy, create_dir_all, read_dir, remove_file, DirEntry},
    io,
    path::PathBuf,
};

use rfd::{FileDialog, MessageDialog, MessageLevel};

#[derive(Default)]
struct UndertaleSave {
    file0: Option<DirEntry>,
    file8: Option<DirEntry>,
    file9: Option<DirEntry>,
    undertale_ini: Option<DirEntry>,
}

impl UndertaleSave {
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.file0.is_none()
            && self.file8.is_none()
            && self.file9.is_none()
            && self.undertale_ini.is_none()
    }

    fn set(&mut self, d: DirEntry) {
        match d.file_name().to_str() {
            Some("file0") => self.file0 = Some(d),
            Some("file8") => self.file8 = Some(d),
            Some("file9") => self.file9 = Some(d),
            Some("undertale.ini") => self.undertale_ini = Some(d),

            _ => {}
        }
    }

    fn final_path(filename: &str) -> PathBuf {
        let mut p = game_save_dir();
        p.push(filename);
        p
    }

    fn load(&self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        for path in ["file0", "file8", "file9", "undertale.ini"].map(Self::final_path) {
            remove_file(path)?;
        }

        for file in [&self.file0, &self.file8, &self.file9, &self.undertale_ini]
            .into_iter()
            .flatten()
        {
            copy(file.path(), game_save_dir())?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

// TODO let the app let you automatically load save files
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
fn saves_dir() -> PathBuf {
    let mut p = dirs::home_dir().unwrap();
    p.push("undertale_saves");
    p
}

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
fn saves_dir() -> PathBuf {
    let mut p = dirs::data_local_dir().unwrap();
    p.push("undertale_saves");
    p
}

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
fn game_save_dir() -> PathBuf {
    let mut p = dirs::home_dir().unwrap();
    p.push(".config/UNDERTALE_linux_steamver");
    p
}

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
fn game_save_dir() -> PathBuf {
    let mut p = dirs::data_local_dir().unwrap();
    p.push("UNDERTALE_linux_steamver");
    p
}

fn main() {
    if !saves_dir().exists() {
        create_dir_all(saves_dir()).ok();
    }
    let folder = FileDialog::new().set_directory(saves_dir()).pick_folder();

    if let Some(folder) = folder {
        match read_dir(folder) {
            Ok(subfolder) => {
                let mut save_directory = UndertaleSave::default();

                for file in subfolder.flatten() {
                    save_directory.set(file);
                }

                if save_directory.is_empty() {
                    MessageDialog::new()
                            .set_description("Folder does not contain any undertale save files. No copy will be performed")
                            .set_level(MessageLevel::Error)
                            .show();
                } else if let Err(e) = save_directory.load() {
                    MessageDialog::new()
                        .set_description(
                            format!("Could not load save file, got error {e}").as_str(),
                        )
                        .set_level(MessageLevel::Error)
                        .show();
                };
            }
            Err(e) => {
                MessageDialog::new()
                    .set_description(format!("Could not open folder, got error {e}").as_str())
                    .set_level(MessageLevel::Error)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```